# Merge two tables in one SQL query and use table names as column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables which you can also find in the `SQL fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c367e/1) :

```
CREATE TABLE Inbound (
    Inbound_Date DATE,
    Product TEXT,
    InboundType TEXT,
    Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Inbound
(Inbound_Date, Product, InboundType, Quantity)
VALUES 
("2017-05-23", "Product A", "Supplier", "400"),
("2018-09-10", "Product B", "Supplier", "200"),
("2018-12-14", "Product B", "Supplier", "600"),
("2019-01-03", "Product A", "Return", "700"),
("2019-02-15", "Product C", "Supplier", "650"),
("2017-09-04", "Product C", "Supplier", "380"),
("2019-01-09", "Product A", "Return", "120"),
("2019-02-16", "Product A", "Return", "470"),
("2019-02-12", "Product A", "Supplier", "920"),
("2019-02-15", "Product C", "Return", "860"),
("2018-01-03", "Product B", "Supplier", "610");


CREATE TABLE Outbound (
    Outbound_Date DATE,
    Product TEXT,
    OutboundType TEXT
);

INSERT INTO Outbound
(Outbound_Date, Product, OutboundType)
VALUES 
("2017-05-23", "Product A", "Sale_US"),
("2018-12-18", "Product B", "Sale_DE"),
("2018-12-18", "Product B", "Sale_DE"),
("2019-02-01", "Product A", "Sale_DE"),
("2019-02-22", "Product C", "Sale_FR"),
("2017-10-18", "Product C", "Sale_NL"),
("2019-04-12", "Product A", "Sale_US"),
("2019-04-12", "Product A", "Sale_FR"),
("2019-04-12", "Product A", "Sale_FR"),
("2019-04-19", "Product C", "Sale_US"),
("2018-05-17", "Product B", "Sale_DE");
```

I use the following VBA to merge the two tables:

```
(SELECT 
   Inbound_Date As Date, 
   Product, 
   SUM(Quantity) as Quantity
 FROM Inbound
 GROUP BY 1,2
) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT
   Outbound_Date,
   Product,
   COUNT("Outbound_Type") 
 FROM Outbound
 GROUP BY 1,2
)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

All this works perfectly.

---

However, now I want that the name of the tables are used as column names. 
In the end the result should look like this:

```
Date           Product       Inbound        Outbound
2017-05-13     Product A     400            0
2017-05-13     Product A     0              1
2017-09-04     Product C     380            0
2017-10-18     Product C     0              1
:              :             :              :
:              :             :              :
:              :             :              :
```

What do I need to change in my code to make it work?
:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try with below query ([SQL-FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c367e/9)):

```
(SELECT 
   Inbound_Date As Date, 
   Product, 
   SUM(Quantity) as Inbound, 0 as Outbound
 FROM Inbound
 GROUP BY 1,2
) 

UNION ALL

(SELECT
   Outbound_Date,
   Product,
   0 as Inbound, COUNT("Outbound_Type")  as Outbound 
 FROM Outbound
 GROUP BY 1,2
)

ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: Any idea for this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique

Answer (score 0):

Alas, MySQL does not support `full join`s. You can work around this with `union all` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Product,
    COALESCE(MAX(Inbound), 0) Inbound,
    COALESCE(MAX(Outbound, 0) Outboud
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Inbound_Date As Date, 
        Product, 
        SUM(Quantity) as Inbound,
        null as Outbound
    FROM Inbound
    GROUP BY Inbound_Date, Product
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Outbound_Date,
        Product,
        null,
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM Outbound
    GROUP BY Outbound_Date, Product
)
GROUP BY Date, Product
ORDER BY Date, Product;
```