# How to compare multiple columns, on multiple rows - comparison only applicable within rows who hold common ID

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

Every record in table has a course_id (auto incremented), a study_id (refers to a patient, each patient can have multiple records in this table), and each record contains a start_date and a stop_date.

I am looking to compare within each patient's records, to see if any of these date ranges overlap. However, I want to do this for all the patients in this table.

For example:

```
course_id  study_id  start_date  stop_date

1234123    12222     01/09/2019  01/12/2019
1444233    12222     01/10/2019  01/01/2020
```

Desired result of query:

```
study_id

12222
```

etc etc for all study_ids with similar overlaps in the start/stop dates.

Hoping someone could lead me in the right direction at least. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text.

Comment: For your reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique) is what a fully constructed question looks like. For tips and tools to use to improve your question, here is a good reference article. [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: @GMB - Thank you for the tips - new here!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this does what you want:

```
select distinct study_id
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.course_id <> t.course_id
        and t1.study_id = t.study_id
        and t1.start_date <= t.end_date
        and t1.end_date   >= t.start_date
)
```

This works by using a correlated subquery with an `exists` condition that filters on record for which another record exists with the same `study_id` and an overlaping date range. Then, the outer query uses `distinct` to remove duplicate `study_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Using selfjoin

```
select distinct t.study_id
from yourtable t
join yourtable t2 on t.study_id = t2.study_id
  and t.course_id > t2.course_id
  and t.start_date <= t2.stop_date
  and t2.start_date <= t.stop_date
```