# If string contains any value from another column, return that value - SQL Informix

Tags: sql, string, informix

I have one column that has very lengthy string, and somewhere (not in a precise location) is a 3 digit number that I want to extract. That part of a string, can be anything from a defined list of another one-column table.

So, if part of the string contains a defined value from a column, return that value. How can I do this with Informix SQL?

Thanks!

This is a string from which I want to extract info:

```
Insert nalog14: 8880888802981130 GERARD BUTLER  KLEVER STR.37 null XANTEN GERMANY null null null 0045000000000 COMERZ AGILE AD null 02085020 01 null Wed Feb 05 00:00:00 CET 2020 978 null 6496.14 NL69ABNA0494540044 Brandsma Yachtservice Eeltjebaasweg 6-8 Sneek THE NETHERLAND 00 528 A 528 null ABNANL2AXXX DOMESTICUSAMSTERDAM This is some random text 130 Invoice number 112362 Repair of Brandsma Vlet Winter Storage Brandsma Vlet null S null 0 null 000 0 null 0 null 1 GERADS SE
```

And let's say that this is my referent column:

```
220
150
400
300
130
112
...
```

So my string contains value '130' there after 'This is some random text' part of the string, and that values is also in referent column.

My desired output is just to extract that value from a string.

```
130
```

What is also problematic is that part of the string that I want to extract can also be present somewhere else in the string, as you can see at the beginning 
8880888802981**130**, but this occurred by chance. Only pattern that I can recognize is that desired output is always separated with blank space before and after.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Help us help you by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60209507/edit) your question and adding more detail. For your reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique) is what a fully constructed question looks like. For tips and tools to use to improve your question, here is a good reference article. [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Please include table and column names — it makes it easier to write an answer, and provides a basis for the answers being consistent.  Otherwise, people have to make up table and column names, and that's a nuisance for everyone.  Also include the column types — there could be issues if `line` is a TEXT or CLOB value rather than CHAR, VARCHAR, LVARCHAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that there is a table `Table1` with:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( …, line LVARCHAR, … );
CREATE TABLE Table2 (number CHAR(3) NOT NULL);
```

I'm also assuming that all the numbers in `Table2` are 3-digit numbers.

You could use the [`INSTR`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2336.htm#ids_sqs_2336) (in-string) function:

```
 SELECT t2.number
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON INSTR(t1.line, " " || t2.number || " ") != 0
```

where the values to be searched for are all 3-digit numbers (or 3-character strings, at any rate).  If you are dealing with variable length data and the type in `Table2` is not a variable-length type, then you need to apply `TRIM` to `t2.number`.  It would be nice to avoid concatenation operations.  If you can modify `Table2` so that `number CHAR(5) NOT ULL` and the numbers are inserted with a leading space (there'll be a trailing space after the three-digit numbers automatically), then you can use

```
 SELECT TRIM(t2.number)
   FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON INSTR(t1.line, t2.number) != 0
```

If the numbers are variable length, this won't work — the concatenation is necessary, and you need to trim the values before using them in the comparison:

```
 SELECT t2.number
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON INSTR(t1.line, " " || TRIM(t2.number) || " ") != 0
```

As noted in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60212221/15168) by [Antonio J. Ortiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9125950/antonio-j-ortiz), you could also use the `LIKE` operator instead of the `INSTR` function, or the `MATCHES` operator.

Answer (score 1):

**table1**:

```
line
------
"Insert nalog14: 8880888802981130 GERARD..."
```

**table2**:

```
number
------
"220"
"150"
"400"
```

...

```
select number
from table1,table2
where line like "%"||trim(number)||"%"
```

Comment: To meet the 'surrounded by spaces' criterion, you'd need to use `WHERE line LIKE "% " || TRIM(number) || " %"` where the crucial change is the blank after and before the `%` symbols.  If the column in Table2 (it's a nuisance that the question doesn't name the tables, isn't it?) is a CHAR(3), the TRIM is not necessary.

Comment: Also, you should aim to use the explicit JOIN notation: `SELECT t2.number FROM Table1 AS t1 JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.line LIKE "% " || TRIM(t2.number) || " %";`.  The 'real' query would presumably select some other information from Table1 so as to identify which row contained the number found.