# SQL: Query the same column 3 times with 3 different where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, conditional-aggregation

Trying to show a table with 3 columns that are prices that need to be displayed. the columns are differentiated by 'price_type' and there are 3 different price types.

Its probably something obvious im missing but something like:

```
Select price as 'current', price as '10min', price as '30min'
from table
where Price_Type(current) = 'current' AND Price_Type(10min) = '10min' AND 
Price_Type(30min) = '30min'
Order by date desc
```

I'm not sure what the actual syntax would be, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Read this [well structured question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60230754/edit) your question with sample data, table structure and desired results to help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
  max(case when Price_Type = 'current' then price end) as [current],
  max(case when Price_Type = '10min' then price end) as [10min],
  max(case when Price_Type = '30min' then price end) as [30min]
from table
group by date
order by date desc
```

Comment: Holy you're a life saver. Thanks so much!!