# SQL query that displays the current date and count of days between two specific dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query that shows the count of the days and date depending upon the financial period it falls in. The financial period starts 5 days before the month end eg march 27th to 26th April

For the above mentioned period if the day is 29th march, the count of the day should be 3 and the date should be 2020-04. The date should adjust depending upon the period it falls in.

I tried to adress the second part of this query by writing the below script but it does not bring any result

```
declare @date datetime
set @date = getdate()
SELECT format (date,'yyyy-MM-dd') as date

where @date

between dateadd(day,-5,EOMONTH(getdate(),-1)) and dateadd(day,-5,EOMONTH(getdate()))
```

Comment: Your financial periods have different numbers of days.  If the date is Jan 25th, there is no corresponding date in the Feb financial period.  Hence, your question needs a lot more explanation about the business rules.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Read this [well structured question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60232847/edit) your question with additional details to help us help you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Thank you for responding, I have edited the actual post by putting in a short script to address a part of this question so can you check it.

Comment: `declare @d date = '20200329';
select 
iif(@d < dateadd(day, -5, EOMONTH (@d, 0)), dateadd(day, -5, EOMONTH (@d, -1)) , dateadd(day, -5, EOMONTH (@d, 0))) as startoffinancialmonth,
datediff(day, iif(@d < dateadd(day, -5, EOMONTH (@d, 0)), dateadd(day, -5, EOMONTH (@d, -1)) , dateadd(day, -5, EOMONTH (@d, 0))), @d) daysdiff;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated to include 5 days from previous month.

Is this what you are looking for the second part?

Edit: Modifying the query. I guess this should give you what you need for both the parts. 
you can try changing the dates in set @date.

Please note that the -4 instead of -5 is done intentionally as you said the financial month starts 5 days earlier. For March, 31 - 5 would give 26, but it should start on 27 right?  so that on 29th the no. of days should be 3 including 27 and 29. Anyways, the query should be self explanatory, might just need to change the number depending on your requirement.

```
declare @date datetime
--set @date = getdate()
set @date = '2020-02-14'

SELECT format(@date,'yyyy-MM-dd') as date,
case WHEN @date < dateadd(day,-4,EOMONTH(@date)) THEN format(EOMONTH(@date),'yyyy-MM')
     ELSE format(EOMONTH(@date, 1),'yyyy-MM') END
     AS FinancialMonth,
     CASE WHEN @date < dateadd(day,-4,EOMONTH(@date)) THEN DATEDIFF(day,dateadd(day,-5,EOMONTH(@date,-1)), @date)
     ELSE DATEDIFF(day, dateadd(day,-5,EOMONTH(@date)), @date) END
     AS CountDays
```

Comment: Hi Viraj, thank you for looking into it. Your answer is very close but the count days is not including the days in the previous month for example when I write                                set @date = '2020-3-20' it gives 20 days but infact it should give 25 by including the 5 days in Feb

Comment: hi Tony. That's right. I missed that part. I edited my query to include 5 days from the previous month. Hope it helps.

Comment: did this work? if it did then you can mark it as answered. I'm also curious to know if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you Viraj, it did work. I have marked it as answered

Answer (score 0):

The following code will calculate what you need. Please read the comments in the code itself.

```
-- First, lets declare all the variables we need.
-- I tried to name them so they are selfexplanatory.
declare @inputdate DateTime, 
            @financialPeriodStartDate DateTime,
            @EndOfTheMonth DateTime,
            @nextFinantialMonthYear DateTime,
            @previousFinancialPeriodStartDate DateTime
-- Now we calculate some of the values
    set @inputdate = GETDATE() -- Let's use Today's date, but you can change this to any date.
    set @EndOfTheMonth = EOMONTH(@inputdate) -- This is the end of the month for the input date
    set @financialPeriodStartDate = DATEADD(DAY,-5,EOMONTH(@inputdate)) -- This is you Financial Period Start Date for the giving input date.
    set @previousFinancialPeriodStartDate = DATEADD(DAY,-5,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @inputdate))) -- Also calculates the Start Date of the precious financial period.
    set @nextFinantialMonthYear = DATEADD(MONTH, 1,@financialPeriodStartDate) -- This is the start date of the next financial period.

-- In the following Select, it calculates the values you need, based in the previous variables.
    select 
    @inputdate as Today,
    @EndOfTheMonth as EndOfMonth,
    @previousFinancialPeriodStartDate as PreviousFinancialPeriodStartDate,
    @financialPeriodStartDate as FinacialPeriodStartDate,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY , @financialPeriodStartDate, @inputdate + 1  ) < 0
         THEN DATEDIFF(DAY , @previousFinancialPeriodStartDate, @inputdate + 1  ) 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY , @financialPeriodStartDate, @inputdate + 1  ) >=0
         THEN DATEDIFF(DAY , @financialPeriodStartDate, @inputdate + 1  )
    END as DaysFromFPStartDate,
    STR(YEAR(@nextFinantialMonthYear)) +'-'+LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(MONTH(@nextFinantialMonthYear)))) as NextFinantialPeriodMonthAndYear
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Code-only answers usually don't help much. This may work, but if you don't explain it to the poster, and to anyone who might come along in the future, it's just a code block.