# Pulling a sub population out of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to identify account numbers that meet a condition for one month but don't meet that condition for the next month. So, pretty much trying to identify account numbers that change in state from one month to the next. The problem for me isn't finding the two sub populations but I'm unsure how to go about comparing the two and getting the accounts numbers that I need. It's been a long day so this might be really easy.

I have a field for month, account#, and the condition which we can just say is true or false.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: To help us help you, please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Take a look at this [well-structured question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique), then [edit]() your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply looking for the lead/lag functions here. You can use these functions to get the information for the previous month here. This should get you started:

```
with cte as
(
select CAST('01Jan2019' as date) as Month,1 as accountno,1 as Condition_Flag UNION
select CAST('01Feb2019' as date) as Month,1 as accountno,0 as Condition_Flag UNION
select CAST('01Mar2019' as date) as Month,1 as accountno,0 as Condition_Flag UNION
select CAST('01Apr2019' as date) as Month,1 as accountno,1 as Condition_Flag UNION
select CAST('01Jan2019' as date) as Month,2 as accountno,1 as Condition_Flag UNION
select CAST('01Feb2019' as date) as Month,2 as accountno,1 as Condition_Flag UNION
select CAST('01Mar2019' as date) as Month,2 as accountno,0 as Condition_Flag UNION
select CAST('01Apr2019' as date) as Month,2 as accountno,0 as Condition_Flag 
)

select *,
    lag(Condition_Flag) Over(Partition by Accountno Order by Month) as lag_condition,
    CASE WHEN Condition_flag is not NULL and 
                Condition_Flag!=lag(Condition_Flag) Over(Partition by Accountno Order by Month) then 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No' End as IsChange
from cte
```