# Using int identity(1,1) as a way to join temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, temp-tables

I'm rewriting a stored procedure that uses int identity(1,1) in >10 temp tables as a way to join these temp tables in the select statement. Below a shorter version of how how the code structure but in the stored procedure I'm editing there this structure is used to return data from each temp table.

```
      CREATE TABLE #temp_MemberInfo
(   RecID               int identity(1,1),
    MemberMBI           varchar(13),
    MemberName          varchar(50),
    MemberAddress       varchar(150), -- DMP
    MemberAddress2      varchar(100), -- DMP
    MemberCity          varchar(50),
    MemberState         varchar(3),
    MemberZip           varchar(11),
    MemberMedicalRecordNo   varchar(20), 
    MemberIsMale        varchar(10),
    MemberIsFemale      varchar(10) 
)
    CREATE TABLE #temp_ProviderInfo
(
    RecID               int identity(1,1),
    ProviderNPI         varchar(13),
    ProviderName            varchar(60), -- DMP
    ProviderAddress     varchar(150), -- DMP
    ProviderAddress2        varchar(100), -- DMP
    ProviderCity            varchar(40),
    ProviderState           varchar(3),
    ProviderZip         varchar(11),
    ProviderTelephone   varchar(15) )


    Select *
    from #temp_MemberInfo
    Inner Join #temp_ProviderInfo on #temp_ProviderInfo.RecID = #temp_MemberInfo.RecID
```

The alternative I can think of would be to use an existing primary key in the date base but I would have to join an extra table in the update statements. Is this better from a performance standpoint? Are there other alternatives I'm not considering?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us help you, please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Take a look at this [well-structured question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60343726/edit) your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @David - you probably want to look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/mcve for an example of how to create a SQL-based question.  As it is, it's hard to tell what the real intention of your code is.

Comment: You can and should join temp tables in the same way you join permanent tables (and table variables). You must find common ground, a piece of information with the same meaning in both tables. If that sequential/positional is relative for both tables it can work, but it smells bad