# Recursion? How can I group orders by common items

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, grouping, rollup

The setup is this.  I have Orders and OrderDetails and the OrderDetails have an Item Number.  Orders have many OrderDetails.  Out of ~1000 Orders with ~10,000 OrderDetail lines, I need the Top 16 Orders that have the most Items in common.

After a week of research, here's my attempt.  When I got to the 8th iteration, I had to stop.  It was a loop but I couldn't figure out how to set the temp table names dynamically.  I also couldn't figure out how to determine when I had the 16 best Orders.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PartNums') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #PartNums
--Gets the part number that is in the most orders
CREATE TABLE #PartNums (ctr int Identity, PartNum varchar(50), CONT int)
INSERT INTO #PartNums SELECT TOP(1) D.PartNum, Count(D.PartNum) AS CONT FROM OrderDetails D
group by  D.PartNum
order by CONT desc

--Gets the orders that have the number one part number in it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Orders
CREATE TABLE #Orders ( Id int, Ord1 varchar(50), Ord2 varchar(50),PartNum varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Orders SELECT O.Id,O.Ord1,O.Ord2, D.PartNum
FROM            OrderDetails D INNER JOIN
                         Orders O ON D.OrderId = O.Id
                         where D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums WHERE ctr = 1)

-- Using just the orders that have the number 1 part number
-- Get the part number that is next most popular in the orders
--Exclude the first part number from the grouping

INSERT INTO #PartNums SELECT TOP(1)  D.PartNum, Count(D.PartNum) as CONT from OrderDetails D inner join #Orders O ON O.Id = D.OrderId
where NOT D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums)
group by D.PartNum
order by CONT desc


--Gets the orders that have the number one part number in it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders2') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Orders2
CREATE TABLE #Orders2 ( Id int, Ord1 varchar(50), Ord2 varchar(50),PartNum varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Orders2 SELECT O.Id,O.Ord1,O.Ord2, D.PartNum
FROM            OrderDetails D INNER JOIN
                         #Orders O ON D.OrderId = O.Id
                         where D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums WHERE ctr = 2)


INSERT INTO #PartNums SELECT TOP(1)  D.PartNum, Count(D.PartNum) as CONT from OrderDetails D inner join #Orders2 O ON O.Id = D.OrderId
where NOT D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums)
group by D.PartNum
order by CONT desc


--Gets the orders that have the number one part number in it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders3') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Orders3
CREATE TABLE #Orders3 ( Id int, Ord1 varchar(50), Ord2 varchar(50),PartNum varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Orders3 SELECT O.Id,O.Ord1,O.Ord2, D.PartNum
FROM            OrderDetails D INNER JOIN
                         #Orders2 O ON D.OrderId = O.Id
                         where D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums WHERE ctr = 3)


INSERT INTO #PartNums SELECT TOP(1)  D.PartNum, Count(D.PartNum) as CONT from OrderDetails D inner join #Orders3 O ON O.Id = D.OrderId
where NOT D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums)
group by D.PartNum
order by CONT desc


--Gets the orders that have the number one part number in it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders4') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Orders4
CREATE TABLE #Orders4 ( Id int, Ord1 varchar(50), Ord2 varchar(50),PartNum varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Orders4 SELECT O.Id,O.Ord1,O.Ord2, D.PartNum
FROM            OrderDetails D INNER JOIN
                         #Orders3 O ON D.OrderId = O.Id
                         where D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums WHERE ctr = 4)


INSERT INTO #PartNums SELECT TOP(1)  D.PartNum, Count(D.PartNum) as CONT from OrderDetails D inner join #Orders4 O ON O.Id = D.OrderId
where NOT D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums)
group by D.PartNum
order by CONT desc


--Gets the orders that have the number one part number in it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders5') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Orders5
CREATE TABLE #Orders5 ( Id int, Ord1 varchar(50), Ord2 varchar(50),PartNum varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Orders5 SELECT O.Id,O.Ord1,O.Ord2, D.PartNum
FROM            OrderDetails D INNER JOIN
                         #Orders4 O ON D.OrderId = O.Id
                         where D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums WHERE ctr = 5)

INSERT INTO #PartNums SELECT TOP(1)  D.PartNum, Count(D.PartNum) as CONT from OrderDetails D inner join #Orders5 O ON O.Id = D.OrderId
where NOT D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums)
group by D.PartNum
order by CONT desc


--Gets the orders that have the number one part number in it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders6') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Orders6
CREATE TABLE #Orders6 ( Id int, Ord1 varchar(50), Ord2 varchar(50),PartNum varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Orders6 SELECT O.Id,O.Ord1,O.Ord2, D.PartNum
FROM            OrderDetails D INNER JOIN
                         #Orders5 O ON D.OrderId = O.Id
                         where D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums WHERE ctr = 6)

INSERT INTO #PartNums SELECT TOP(1)  D.PartNum, Count(D.PartNum) as CONT from OrderDetails D inner join #Orders6 O ON O.Id = D.OrderId
where NOT D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums)
group by D.PartNum
order by CONT desc

--Gets the orders that have the number one part number in it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders7') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Orders7
CREATE TABLE #Orders7( Id int, Ord1 varchar(50), Ord2 varchar(50),PartNum varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Orders7 SELECT O.Id,O.Ord1,O.Ord2, D.PartNum
FROM            OrderDetails D INNER JOIN
                         #Orders6 O ON D.OrderId = O.Id
                         where D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums WHERE ctr = 7)


INSERT INTO #PartNums SELECT TOP(1)  D.PartNum, Count(D.PartNum) as CONT from OrderDetails D inner join #Orders7 O ON O.Id = D.OrderId
where NOT D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums)
group by D.PartNum
order by CONT desc


--Gets the orders that have the number one part number in it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders8') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Orders8
CREATE TABLE #Orders8( Id int, Ord1 varchar(50), Ord2 varchar(50),PartNum varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Orders8 SELECT O.Id,O.Ord1,O.Ord2, D.PartNum
FROM            OrderDetails D INNER JOIN
                         #Orders7 O ON D.OrderId = O.Id
                         where D.PartNum IN (SELECT partNum from #PartNums WHERE ctr = 7)

SELECT DISTINCT OrderId FROM OrderDetails where PartNum in (SELECT partNum from #PartNums);

SELECT * FROM #Orders8;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us help you, please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Take a look at this [well-structured question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60344350/edit) your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does that help to clarify what I need?

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid. Take a look at [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for a clearer idea of what the volunteers on the site are looking for.

Comment: Why did you add the same code over and over to your question? That's just noise and almost the opposite of the [mcve] that everybody likes to see here.

Answer (score 0):

Because no DDL was given, i create a 'simple' example on this [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0faf50818d8709c5373d597350da10ae)

```
SELECT 
    Parts, 
    STRING_AGG(id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Id) as PartsCombinationInOrder,
    COUNT(*)           as NumberOfTimes
FROM (
  SELECT
     Orders.Id, STRING_AGG(Order_details.Part_no,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Order_details.Part_no) as Parts
  FROM Orders
  INNER JOIN Order_Details on Order_Details.Order_id = Orders.Id
  GROUP BY Orders.Id
) x
GROUP BY x.Parts
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

For a short explanation on ho STRING_AGG() works see: [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

This will first get all articles on every order, than group on the combination of these articles, and order them descending. The most favorite combination should be on top.

EDIT:

Another attempt to find all combinations of articles in orders

```
WITH Orders as(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) Orders(Order_Id)
    )
    , Order_Details as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
            (1,1,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,3),(1,4,4),(1,5,5),(1,6,6),
            (2,1,1),(2,2,2),(2,3,3),(2,4,4),(2,5,5),(2,6,6),
            (3,1,1),(3,2,2),(3,3,3),(3,4,4),(3,5,5),(3,6,6), 
            (4,1,1),(4,2,2),(4,3,7),(4,4,3),(4,5,5),(4,6,6)
        ) Order_Details(Order_id,Line_no,Part_no) 
    ),combinations as (
    SELECT o.Order_Id, 
        od1.Line_no as Line1, od1.Part_no as Part1, 
        od2.Line_no as Line2, od2.Part_no as Part2, 
        od3.Line_no as Line3, od3.Part_no as Part3
    FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Order_Details od1 ON od1.Order_id = o.Order_Id       
    INNER JOIN Order_Details od2 ON od2.Order_id = o.Order_Id AND od2.Line_no > od1.Line_no
    INNER JOIN Order_Details od3 ON od3.Order_id = o.Order_Id AND od3.Line_no > od2.Line_no AND od3.Line_no > od1.Line_no
    )
SELECT c.Order_Id, c.Part1, c.Part2, c.Part3, q.count
FROM combinations c
CROSS APPLY (SELECT count(*) as count FROM combinations q WHERE q.Part1=c.Part1 and q.Part2=c.Part2 and q.Part3=c.Part3) q
ORDER BY q.count DESC,c.Part1,c.Part2,c.Part3, c.Order_Id;
```

output:

```
Order_Id    Part1       Part2       Part3       count
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           2           3           4
2           1           2           3           4
3           1           2           3           4
4           1           2           3           4
1           1           2           5           4
2           1           2           5           4
✂✂✂✂✂
4           3           5           6           4
1           1           2           4           3
2           1           2           4           3
3           1           2           4           3
1           1           3           4           3
2           1           3           4           3
3           1           3           4           3
1           1           4           5           3
✂✂✂✂✂
2           4           5           6           3
3           4           5           6           3
4           1           2           7           1
4           1           7           3           1
4           1           7           5           1
4           1           7           6           1
4           2           7           3           1
4           2           7           5           1
4           2           7           6           1
4           7           3           5           1
4           7           3           6           1
4           7           5           6           1

(80 rows affected)
```

I Think this piece is easy expandable to have 'Part4','Part5',etc, which allows combinations of more than 3 articles which is show above.

Comment: The example returns a list of orders that are "exactly" the same.   The Orders are not the same but have many parts in common.   I need to know which Orders have the most common part numbers down to the least.  I have worked on the  [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0faf50818d8709c5373d597350da10ae)  and added comments to it to describe what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: OK, i understand, will tink about this..... , the link to the fiddle you posted is the same as the link i posted... (your changes are lost?)

Comment: Here is the updated [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8df334a2dad7a691e9897c0e91e95f22)

Comment: Note: Step2 returns the same records as Step1 (expect for article3), also note that in step 2 you should not only leave out article3, but the orders selected there should also have a line with article3 otherwise there will no be a combination of article3 with the found article.... (difficult to explain this is....)

Comment: Yes, everything you said it true, especially (difficult to explain).  I'm sure the problem is how I'm trying to explain the question by using MY attempt at a  solution that I'm now positive is wrong.  When you're helping to find a solution, you should not use any of my previous attempts.  So, with that in mind, I want to reframe the question to make it as clear as I can in the next comment.

Comment: `combinations` are selected on Line_no of order_details. This could be a problem if one order has Part_no `1,2,3` and another `1,3,2`. This example *assumes* Part_no are ordered the same way as Line_no (which, of course, the are not in real life)