# Write a SQL query to calculate the balance in a card

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

Can you please help me how to calculate the balance for each quarter

The data table

[image]

**Script to create the table:**

Create Table CardTransactions
(
CardId varchar(10),
Trans_num int,
Quarter varchar(25),
TransactionAmount float,
Balance_Trans float
)

insert into CardTransactions values

('Card1',   1,  'FQ-2013-4',    10  ,   5       ),
('Card1',   2,  'FQ-2013-4',    3.65,   1.35    ),
('Card1',   3,  'FQ-2014-1',    -10 ,   11.35   ),
('Card1',   4,  'FQ-2014-1',    -10 ,   21.35   ),
('Card1',   5,  'FQ-2014-1',    4.2 ,   17.15   ),
('Card1',   6,  'FQ-2014-3',    2   ,   15.15   ),
('Card1',   7,  'FQ-2014-3',    1.15,   14      ),
('Card1',   8,  'FQ-2014-4',    -20 ,   34      ),
('Card1',   9,  'FQ-2014-4',    5.15,   28.85   ),
('Card1',   10, 'FQ-2015-3',    4   ,   24.85   ),
('Card1',   11, 'FQ-2015-3',    2.5 ,   22.35   ),
('Card1',   12, 'FQ-2015-3',    2.35,   20      )

select * from CardTransactions;

**Expected result:** Need the result like this

[image]

I've tried to run this query like this but not working

```
select 
   distinct ct1.CardId, 
   ct1.Quarter,
   ct2.Balance_Trans-ct1.TransactionAmount balance, 
   ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ct1.Quarter order by ct1.Quarter) rn
from CardTransactions ct1
join  CardTransactions ct2
   on ct1.Trans_num >= ct2.Trans_num;
```

Comment: This would be *far* easier if you were using a supported version of SQL Server. 2008 doesn't support cumulative sums without using the "quirky" feature or a triangular join. Considering SQL Server 2008 has been out of support for well over a year, i would suggest it's well past time to update.

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. What should happen? What happens instead?

Comment: I'm running this in SQL Server 2016. Can you please help by sharing this SQL query?

Comment: "*I'm running this in SQL Server 2016"* Then why have you tagged [tag:sql-server-2008]?

Comment: @underscore_d 

I've also tried like this 
select distinct ct1.CardId, ct1.Quarter, null
from CardTransactions ct1
UNION ALL
Select null, null,cast(ct1.Balance_Trans as varchar(50)) --ct1.TransactionAmount,ct1.Balance_Trans-ct1.TransactionAmount balance 
from CardTransactions ct1

However, the expected result is for balance calculation is not coming.

Comment: Also, please don't post images of data. Take the time to post it in a **consumable** format; preferably DDL and DML statements, however, if not tabular formatted `text`. Don't forget to show the expected results and **explain** the logic to get to those results too.

Comment: @Larnu I've shared the format of expected result.

Comment: I see you've removed SQL Server 2008, but added 2012 (along with 2016). So are you using both 2016 and 2012? *" I've shared the format of expected result."* "need" isn't an explanation.

Comment: For your reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique) is what a fully constructed SQL question looks like. For tips and tools to use to improve your question, here is a good reference article. [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the last `balance_trans` for each card and quarter.

One method is:

```
select ct.*
from (select ct.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cardid, quarter order by trans_num desc) as seqnum
      from CardTransactions ct
     ) ct
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also express this as:

```
select ct.*
from CardTransactions ct
where ct.trans_num = (select max(ct2.trans_num)
                      from CardTransactions ct2
                      where ct2.cardid = ct.cardid and 
                            ct2.quarter = ct.quarter
                     );
```