# combine SQL Statements with a IN list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think I have a simple request but just do not seem to find the answer... Also google is not my friend at the moment.. :)

I have a list (of integer) with Items

And I have 2 tables in the DB:

```
Tabel Count:

CountDate,
item
```

I am interested in the latest date the items are counted..

```
Tabel pick:
PickDate , 
Item
```

The Dates that Items are picked. I am interested in the amount of picks after the last time the item was counted, So;

Amount of times (picks) it is picked after the latest date from table count.

I can do:
step 1:

```
“Select ITEM, max(countdate) as countdate from Count where Item = IN (1234,234,345)”
```

Step2 : For each itemnumber I need to do:

```
“SELECT COUNT (item) as amount from PICK where item = itemnumber AND Pickdate >  ResultCountDateStep1”
```

I can not seem to find 1 total query  (for all itemnumbers) for this to get a datateable with:

```
Item    LastCountDate       AmountofPicks
```

Comment: What engine are you using? (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgresql, etc.)?

Comment: Also, can you add some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: Help us help you. For your reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078622/merge-two-tables-in-one-sql-query-and-make-the-date-values-unique) is what a fully constructed question looks like. For tips and tools to use to improve your question, here is a good reference article. [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) Also, [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a CTE, which would work for many versions of different dbms' such as MySQL, Sql Server and Postgres. You may need to slightly modify if you have a different rdbms or older version. You could convert this CTE into a subquery. Basically, you can use the CTE or subquery to get the max date and then join on item.

```
create table count_table (
  item integer, 
  countdate date
  );
  
insert into count_table values 
(1234, '2022-01-01'), 
(1234, '2022-04-15'), 
(234, '2022-05-10'), 
(234, '2022-08-10'), 
(234, '2022-09-10'), 
(345, '2022-10-15');

create table pick_table (
  item integer, 
  pickdate date
  );
  
insert into pick_table values 
(1234, '2022-03-15'), 
(1234, '2022-03-16'), 
(1234, '2022-05-19'), 
(1234, '2022-07-15'), 
(234, '2022-03-15'), 
(234, '2022-10-15'), 
(345, '2022-10-14');
```

---

```
with max_date as (
  select item, max(countdate) as max_dt
  from count_table
  group by item
  )
select p.item, d.max_dt as last_count_date, count(p.item) as amount_of_picks
  from pick_table p 
  join max_date d 
    on p.item = d.item 
 where p.pickdate > d.max_dt 
   --and p.item in (1234, 234, 345)
group by p.item, d.max_dt;
```

| item | last_count_date | amount_of_picks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-04-15 | 2 |
| 234 | 2022-09-10 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fcLzs33eYG6QouChUbP4Lz/0)

---

**UPDATE**

Or if you want to show ALL items, even those with a count of 0 (ie, 0 items with a pick date after last count date), then you could use use conditional aggregation:

```
with max_date as (
  select item, max(countdate) as max_dt
  from count_table
  group by item
  )
select p.item, d.max_dt as last_count_date, 
   sum(case when p.pickdate > d.max_dt then 1 else 0 end) as amount_of_picks
 from pick_table p 
 left join max_date d 
   on p.item = d.item 
--where p.item in (1234, 234, 345)
group by p.item, d.max_dt;
```

| item | last_count_date | amount_of_picks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-04-15 | 2 |
| 234 | 2022-09-10 | 1 |
| 345 | 2022-10-15 | 0 |

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer. Sorry for my question with too little information. I have to leave now but will implement it, but better, try to understand it tomorrow(fresh).. Thanks!